# Find value of column 2 where column 1 contains a specific string in datatable

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable

I have 2 columns in a datatable.

```
CarName, CarNumber
```

The CarName column has a value that follows this pattern (Location-Type of Vehicle + @ + NT Login (samAccountName).

example:

```
SYRA-CAR@RFREEMAN
```

I need to be able to search column 1 in each row to find if it contains my NT Login (ex: "RFREEMAN")
and when found return the value of whatever is inside column 2 of that same row (CarNumber)

Comment: _CarName LIKE '%@RFREEMAN'_ Did you have already loaded the DataTable or are you asking for a WHERE condition? Please update your question with more code that explain the context of your problem

Comment: What language are you using? Please only choose one.

Comment: `SELECT CarNumber FROM TableName WHERE CarName LIKE '%@RFREEMAN'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 Dim res As String
 For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    If (row("CarName").ToString.Contains("RFREEMAN")) Then
         res = row("CarNumber").ToString()
         Exit For
    End If
Next
```

**Edit**

To validate that the string you are searching for is at the right position, use `EndsWith` instead. Like this

```
 Dim res As String
 For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    If (row("CarName").ToString.EndsWith("@RFREEMAN")) Then
         res = row("CarNumber").ToString()
         Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Where `dt` is the name of your data table.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!

Comment: +1 @preciousbetine, but I'd recommend a refinement. The defining characteristics of the username are that it's preceded with `@` and it's at the end of the string, so instead of `.Contains("whatever")` I'd recommend `.EndsWith("@whatever")`. That way there's less risk of getting a false match on a location or vehicle type value. It won't happen for the OP's example data, but for other records and usernames the risk is there.

Comment: @EdGibbs wow, nice suggestion, I will update the answer to include that .